# Can anyone tell me what these parts are and what they do

Tags: identification

On the bottom of this picture there are two boxes. One with what looks like the letter y in a circle and another box which you can turn with a screw driver beside it. 
What I want to know is what are these parts and what do they do?

[image]

The circuit in the picture is the photographing cell that takes the video (don't know the technical name) from a JVC GR-65 (magnetic tape camcorder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are inductors or transformers.  Sometimes they can also contain an internal capacitor.  They are used for interstage coupling and as filters.  The ferrite core in some of these is adjustable - it is threaded like a screw and can be moved in and out of the core to tune the frequency response.

Comment: Example units [here](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/480/489322_DS.pdf)